# How to create a ajax success method with model as a parameter

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am sending selected customername from ui to backend..that method returning model.How to handle model object in Ui.

This is my code.

```
<form:form method="get" action="retrieve" modelAttribute="customer" commandName="customer">
  <b>Environment:</b>
  <form:select path="EnvrironmentId" id="environmentDetails">
    <option selected="selected">Select An Environment</option>
    <form:options items="${map.environmentnamesList}" itemLabel="environmentName" itemValue="envrironmentId"/>
  </form:select>
```

some thing like this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#customerDetails").change(function() {
        var value1 = $('#customerDetails :selected').text();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'environments',
            data: {
                selectedcustomername: value1
            },
            success: function(data) {

            }

        });
    });
});



@RequestMapping(value = "/environments", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getenvironments(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response, @ModelAttribute("customer") Customer customer, @RequestParam String selectedcustomername) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("selected cust name" + selectedcustomername);
    ModelAndView model = null;
    Map < String, Object > map = new HashMap < String, Object > ();
    List < org.mvc.domain.Environments > environmentnamesList = loginDelegate.getEnvironments(selectedcustomername);
    Collections.sort(environmentnamesList, new CustomComparator());
    for (int i = 0; i < environmentnamesList.size() - 1; i++) {
        customer.setEnvrironmentId(environmentnamesList.get(0));
        customer.setEnvironmentName(environmentnamesList.get(1));
    }
    map.put("environmentnamesList", environmentnamesList);
    model = new ModelAndView("welcome", "map", map);
    return model;

}
```

i am getting dropdown values in firebug html section.But i am unable to load same values in main html..

Answer (score 0):

As you are sending ajax request from ui so it is not aware of model in backend, best way is to convert the response to `json` or `html` and consume that in your javascript.

Other solution would be to rendered the page from backend itself and add something like this in jsp

```
<script>
  var model=[];
  model.someparam="${model.someparam}";
  model.anotherparam="${model.anotherparam}";
</script>
```

and in js you can do like this

`alert(model.someparam)`